# Userscript GM_addStyle

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am trying to change background color of the bar under profile picture on facebook (Wall, Informations, Photos etc.) with userscript.. I'm trying to do it like that but it's not working:

```
GM_addStyle("#uiSideNav uiSideNavSection uiFutureSideNavSection{ background-color:#ffffff; }");
```

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a big Facebook user, but the random wall pages I tested had no node with an id of ***uiSideNav***.

Try a selector of `.uiSideNavSection .uiFutureSideNavSection` -- which was present on the pages I sampled.  So use:

```
GM_addStyle(".uiSideNavSection .uiFutureSideNavSection { background-color:#ffffff; }");
```

Note that **you need the dots in front of the class names**.

Also, for just style changes, the [Stylish add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) is better and faster.

Comment: If you use the multiline syntax of GM_addStyle (with a backticks) and if you have some comment, you must use `/*CSS comments*/ ` and not `//Js comments`

Answer (score 1):

uiSideNavSection looks suspicious, since in CSS that would only match an element with that name, i.e. <uiSideNavSection>. Check out the Selectors section of [this tutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/) to learn more.

Did you inspect the DOM you're trying to style with Firebug or Chrome's inspector? If you're unable to figure it out, post the relevant part of the DOM structure here, that might help giving you an answer.

You might also need an `!important` to override page's style: `background-color:#ffffff !important;`.